# Why is string getter returning an empty response?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, string

This is a sequence of [another question I asked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/how-to-store-a-300-char-string).

I have the following contract

```
contract User {
    string publicKey;

    function setPublicKey(string _publicKey)
        onlyOwner
    {
        publicKey = _publicKey;
    }

    function getPublicKey() returns (string _publicKey) {
        return publicKey;
    }

}
```

I have set the string to be

```
5030480389847504049639477069961901518251822532055915812015454717740961852942027334498786032153069913846973579859702642411497486328669598344496363306620763652362226170692287240855050713537819594000868803228735504934019483458523068727831434237837325563417285328158635879852481735301070609988900677951635437637299660610442447448957534545817
```

I called the `setPublicKey()` method with the string value and got back the transaction hash `0x789894f0b5a85cc45e317cb51af27a4d28858e3b64c64ee00118f4543d7a5de7` (it's a private chain).

I then called `getPublicKey()` but just got back an empty reply. Why does this happen?

This seems to be pretty basic but I've googled and checked here and didn't find any information that could answer it.

EDIT: Adding `getPublicKey()` function

```
// Example calling function
function getPublicKey(publicAddress, contractAddress, contractName) {
    // Get the contract code from contracts
    const input = fs.readFileSync('contracts/' + contractName + '.sol').toString();
    const output = solc.compile(input);
    // The trailing ':' is needed otherwise it crashes
    const bytecode = output.contracts[':' + contractName].bytecode;
    const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':' + contractName].interface);
    const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(contractAddress);
    contract.getPublicKey.call((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Public Key is ");
            console.log(res);
        }
    })
}
```

It's a function in my node app.

Comment: did you increase the gas value? and can you also share how you are calling getPublicKey() function.

Comment: Haven't increased the gas value yet and would like to avoid it if possible. Just added the code for the function, cheers!

Comment: You can also try to save smaller string value and after that, if getPublicKey() works then it would indicate that it's a problem related to gas value.

Comment: Maybe you don't mined~

Comment: @Sanchit will try that and report back. And I mined, have made that mistake in the past :)

Comment: I tried changing to a smaller value and I still get nothing back. It should be an error in the code then but I really don't see where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I did not check your code properly earlier, there are some small changes required.

Please check below code, it works for me.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

    contract MyTest {

        string public publicKey;

        function setPublicKey(string _publicKey)
        {
            publicKey = _publicKey;
        }

        function getPublicKey() constant returns (string _publicKey) {
            return publicKey;
        }
    }
```

The getter function has to be constant to return value. That's the main mistake.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You were right, I had to increase the gas value. Sorry for the stubbornness there! Increasing the gas + this code solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.  Just delete the _publicKey in the returns string.

```
contract User {
    string publicKey;

    function setPublicKey(string _publicKey)
    {
        publicKey = _publicKey;
    }

    function getPublicKey() returns (string) {
        return publicKey;
    }

 }
```

Comment: This works if I try to set the string to some small ones but if I try to set it to `5030480389847504049639477069961901518251822532055915812015454717740961852942027334498786032153069913846973579859702642411497486328669598344496363306620763652362226170692287240855050713537819594000868803228735504934019483458523068727831434237837325563417285328158635879852481735301070609988900677951635437637299660610442447448957534545817`, it just returns an empty response.